# Using C# program FNR to find and replace properties, file cannot be found

Tags: regex, cmd, expression

I have a master virtual machine with a few websites hosted on it. When I deploy a copy of this, the settings are a standard value, and I often need to change them so they fit different databases. For this I would like to use a small c# program so I can use regular expressions to find and replace whatever property needed. For this I use fnr (http://findandreplace.codeplex.com/).

findandreplace.bat:

```
set DATABASE="dbname"
set DBHOST="my.host.name"
set DBPORT="1234"
set ENV="this.env"

ECHO CHANGE DATABASE
"fnr" --cl --dir "D:\Inetpub\wwwroot" --fileMask "web.config" --includeSubDirectories --useRegEx --find "<add key=\"DATABASE\" value=\".*\"\s*>" --replace "<add key=\"DATABASE\" value=\"%DATABASE%\">"

ECHO CHANGE HOST
"fnr" --cl --dir "D:\Inetpub\wwwroot" --fileMask "web.config" --includeSubDirectories --useRegEx --find "<add key=\"HOST\" value=\".*\"\s*>" --replace "<add key=\"HOST\" value=\"%DBHOST%\">"

ECHO CHANGE PORT
"fnr" --cl --dir "D:\Inetpub\wwwroot" --fileMask "web.config" --includeSubDirectories --useRegEx --find "<add key=\"ConnectionString\" value=\"Data Source.*>" --replace "<add key=\"ConnectionString\" value=\"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = %%3%%)(port = %DBPORT%)) )(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = %%2%%)));User ID=%%0%%;Password=%%1%%;Enlist=false\">"

set /p await= "any key to continue"
```

Windows command prompt gives me the following output in the end:

```
CHANGE PORT
The system cannot find the file specified.
 "any key to continue"
```

I can see the first two goes through and if I check the files it should touch, the values are changed correctly. I just cannot understand why the change port doesnt work, and tells me it cannot find the file specified. One, it doesnt specify any single file, and two, it looks for the same files as the first two.

Also, if I try to run the regex in FNR (the find part, with same parameters as only web.config files and in the same folder+subfolders) it finds the files perfectly.

Anyone got an idea as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Appearently "<add key=\"ConnectionString\" value=\"Data Source.*>" missed \" before >
I was under the impression .* included " and as such > should end the expression. I was mistaken. Problem solved.